# How to prevent duplicate date entries in PHP?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

The PHP is using Laravel framework and I need to have one date entry per store.

```html
public function store ($id, request $request)
{
  $validation = $this -> validate($request,['date_entry'->'required']);
  $existingEntry = data::where('date_entry',$request->date_entry)->first();
  if(count($existingEntry)>0){
  return redirect()->route('data.create',$id)->withErrors($validation)->withInput();
  }else{
  $store=Store::findorfail($id);
  $log = new data($request->all());
  if($request->submit_type=="submit_save"){
  $log->status_id=2;}
  else{
  $log->status_id=1;}
  $store->db_data()->save($log);
  return redirect()->route('data.show',$id);
  }
```

```
if(count($existingEntry)>0))
```

creates one date entry for the rest of the stores what I want is I'm able to put date entry for each store for 1 day only and it doesn't repeat for the same day.

```
|-----|---------|------------------|
| ID  | Store   |  DateEntry       |
|-----|---------|------------------|
|  1  | Store1  |    9/23/2017     |
|-----|---------|------------------|
|  2  | Store2  |    9/23/2017     |
|-----|---------|------------------|
|  3  | Store3  |    9/23/2017     |
|-----|---------|------------------|
|  4  | Store1  |    9/24/2017     |
```

what my code does is that it only stores 1 date entry and you'll not be able to store other date entries for the other stores, what I want is that I'm able to store date entries for each store but doesn't accept the same date entry.

Comment: I recommend you to learn the fundamentals of DB & core language before diving into the frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Just make this column `unique` in migration file:

```
Schema::create('your_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
    //
    $table->string('Store')->unique();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Validation Rule

```
$request->validate([
   'sample' => 'required|unique:table_name'
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Schema::create('datas', function(Blueprint $tab;e){
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('store');
    $table->string('date_entry')->unique();
    // other attribute goes here;
});
```

when you give a `unique` constraint on column MySQL will throw some error when you insert new Data with the `data_entry` which already exist. But if you did this your application whill throw some exception every time you insert data with date_entry that already exist. To avoid that you must make validation when you insert that data

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'data_entry' => 'required|unique:datas:data_entry',
    // other rules
]);
```

the `required|unique:datas:data_entry` this rule allow eloquent to insure that there are only one element in your table `datas` with the date_entry that your are trying to insert